# Externalization with inner classes

Tags: java, externalizable

I was going through article on Externalization on [this](http://www.jusfortechies.com/java/core-java/externalization.php) site and I found the following para in the limitations of Externalization section.

> As you know a default public no-arg constructor will be called when
>   serializing the objects that implements Externalizable interface.
>   Hence, Externalizable interface can't be implemented by Inner Classes
>   in Java as all the constructors of an inner class in Java will always
>   accept the instance of the enclosing class as a prepended parameter
>   and therefore you can't have a no-arg constructor for an inner class.
>   Inner classes can achieve object serialization by only implementing
>   Serializable interface.

I tested this and turns out this is not valid. Inner classes can have no argument constructor and also they can implement `Externalizable` interface. Even tried it with local classes. Works fine.

```
public class ExternalizeDemo {

    class InnerClass implements Externalizable{

        public InnerClass() {
            //default no-arg inner class constructor
        }

        @Override
        public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
            //logic to save object state
        }

        @Override
        public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
            //logic to retrieve object state
        }
    }

    public void localClassTest(){
        class LocalClass implements Externalizable{

            public LocalClass(){
                //default no-arg local class constructor
            }

            @Override
            public void writeExternal(ObjectOutput out) throws IOException {
                //logic to save object state
            }

            @Override
            public void readExternal(ObjectInput in) throws IOException, ClassNotFoundException {
                //logic to retrieve object state
            }
        }
    }

}
```

So either I am missing some point or the article paragraph is no longer valid (I am using Java 7). So which one is it. Any suggestion is appreciated.

Comment: Did you try serializing and deserializing an instance?

Comment: Protip - avoid serialization and externalization. They're old and rarely actually used anymore. Prefer an external serializer - a class should not be concerned about its own persistence.

Comment: @SotiriosDelimanolis I did not implement the methods just compiled it. But the fact that the article says we cannot have no-arg constructor in inner classes sounds incorrect to me.

Comment: Implementing an interface cannot put such a restriction. I think they meant it will fail at run time.

Comment: The article is poorly worded, but it doesn't actually say it won't compile. It says it can't call the constructor. When you try it you will see. However I'm not in favour of this trend whereby StackOverflow is becoming a review site for random other sites. If you want to cite something you don't understand, please start with the Java Language Specification and the Javadoc. See the [Object Serialization Specification #11.1](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/platform/serialization/spec/serial-arch.html#7185): 'the Externalizable interface mechanism cannot be used for inner classes.'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The paragraph means you cannot create instance of inner class (non static nested class) without an instance of outer class.

So on deserializing to create instance of inner class the code will need somehow to use an instance of the outer class.

You have to call

```
ExternalizeDemo mainClassInstance=some initializing;

mainClassInstance.new InnerClass();
```

Deserializing won't have the mainClassInstance to create the InnerClass instance.

Comment: This makes sense. Saying **constructors of an inner class in Java will always accept the instance of the enclosing class as a prepended parameter** is a bit misleading. Thanks.

Comment: @AniketThakur There is nothing misleading about that correct statement.

Comment: I am just saying it is not as easy to digest as saying all classes implicitly extend Object class. Specifically above statement does not hold true for static inner class I suppose.

Answer (score 0):

It fails at runtime... The below Wizard Class is inner class to SerialiserTest and implements Externalizable

```
Wizard w = new SerialiserTest().new Wizard();
outputStream = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
objectOutputStream = new ObjectOutputStream(outputStream);
objectOutputStream.writeObject(w);
byteArrayInputStream = new ByteArrayInputStream(outputStream.toByteArray());
inputStream = new ObjectInputStream(byteArrayInputStream);
Wizard wiz = (Wizard) inputStream.readObject();

Exception in thread "main" java.io.InvalidClassException: jtk.file.ser.SerialiserTest$Wizard; no valid constructor
at java.io.ObjectStreamClass$ExceptionInfo.newInvalidClassException(ObjectStreamClass.java:150)
```